# Action button macros change when shuffling powerpoint slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a presentation of 24 slides, and on each slide there is some action buttons with macro´s.

I also have a code that shuffles the slides every time someone start the presentation and it works fine.

My problem is that when shuffling the slides, the assigned macro on the buttons changes as well.

Is there a way to make sure that each slides gets shuffled without changing the action buttons macros?

code for the shuffle:

```
Sub shuffleRange()

    Dim Iupper As Integer
    Dim ilower As Integer
    Dim ifrom As Integer
    Dim Ito As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Iupper = 21
    ilower = 2

    If Iupper > ActivePresentation.Slides.Count Or ilower < 1 Then GoTo Err

    For i = 1 To 2 * Iupper
    Randomize
    ifrom = Int((Iupper - ilower + 1) * Rnd + ilower)
    Ito = Int((Iupper - ilower + 1) * Rnd + ilower)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ifrom).MoveTo (Ito)

    Next i

    Exit Sub

Err:
    MsgBox " Shuffle failed", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. Is your problem that the macro is staticly attached to the buttons and as you shuffle your slide, the buttons are also shuffled (e.g. you want button of slide 3 is always on slide 3, no matter where it's getting shuffled)? Or is your problem that the buttons stay in place while the slides were shuffled so that you have the buttons on the wrong slides (e.g. the button on slide 3 stays always on slide 3 even if slide 3 and 4 change position)?

Comment: Can we see the code for the assigned macro on the button and highlight how it changes when the slides are shuffled please?  Is it a case of the code says to do something to the slide in position 3, but that slide is now in position 5 so it's changing the wrong slide?

Comment: I want the buttons be assigned to the actual slide that they are on. And after the shuffle they should still be assigned to the specific button.  But for some reason now, my macros changes when i do the shuffle.  the macro itself only register correct or wrong answers and the send the user to the next slide

Comment: So we can't see the code for the assigned macro then?  I tested the code you've given against a presentation with 11 slides - the command button moved with the slides and the code didn't change.  Slide 6 is now in position 7 and the code is still `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(): Call MyMacro: End Sub`

Comment: Do you mean that the code in the macros changes (unlikely) or that the EFFECT of the code changes?  Is the problem that the macro or action button says "Go to slide 42" and slide 42 moves to another position when you shuffle the slides, so the macro sends the user to the wrong slide?

Comment: The macro only counts correct or wrong +1 and then next slide, but for some reason the correct/Wrong count changes.

Comment: Code on the action Buttons :  
    Sub Correct()
    numberCorrect = numberCorrect + 1
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next

End Sub


Sub Wrong()

    numberWrong = numberWrong + 1
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next

End Sub